# Validate a string for a valid date in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

What I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, "End Date", new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {

    $("#EndDate").datepicker(@if (Model.EndDate != DateTime.MinValue) {
                                     <text>{ defaultDate: new Date('@Model.EndDate') }</text>
                                 });
    @if (Model.EndDate != DateTime.MinValue) {
        <text> $("#EndDate").val('@Model.EndDate.ToShortDateString()'); </text>
    }
    @if (Model.EndDate == DateTime.MinValue) {
        <text> $("#EndDate").attr('disabled', 'true'); </text>
    }
}
```

So the text box is bound to a datepicker and the user has the option to edit the date manually.
I am looking at a way to validate the date entered into the textbox.

For example, the user can enter 85426525455 which is not a valid date, in this case I want to show a vlaidation message when the Save button is clicked.

I tried to add an onClose event that did not work:

```
$("#EndDate").datepicker({
       onClose:function(dateText, inst) {
           try {
               $("#EndDate").datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
           } catch (e) {
               alert(e);
           } 
       }
});
```

Any clues!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you want to use [DataAnnotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724449/validate-textbox-to-accept-only-valid-datetime-value-using-dataannotations-in-mv) For this?

Comment: Why not just include `@Html.ValidationMesageFor(m => m.EndDate)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.datepicker.parseDate()` method this way:

```js
$("#EndDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    try {
      $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id='EndDate'>
```

---

Or just don't allow the user to enter date manually with `readonly` attribute.

```js
$("#EndDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id='EndDate' readonly>
```